# Laravel redirect back with variables

Tags: php, laravel-5

Trying to redirect to the previous page with variables

```
$get_product = Product::where('name',$request->name)->first();
return redirect()->back()->with('get_product',$get_product);
```

but i have [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbyen.png) when i print variable

Comment: Is your query working properly? Have you tried var_dump($get_product); after defining the variable and before returning it?

Comment: Is `$get_product` actually set? `dd($get_product)`

Comment: yes .. i tried return for this variable and results is true